# rendering html in django template?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I am aware this question has been asked before but none of them seem to be working in my case. My html string is being rendered as it is. I am storing a success message like so:

```
msg='You have completed the first step of <a href="some_url">Getting started with MDN</a>'
messages.success(request, msg)
```

And storing it in notifications[] variable:

```
{% if messages %}notifications: [
    {% for message in messages %}{% if 'wiki_redirect' not in message.tags or waffle.flag('redirect_messages') %}{message: {%autoescape off%}"{{ message }}"{% endautoescape %}, tags: "{{ message.tags }}", level: "{{ message|level_tag }}"}{% if not loop.last %},{% endif %}{% endif %}
                {% endfor %}
            ],
            {% else %}
            notifications: [],
            {% endif %}
```

Is there any syntax error in this? If I render it directly, this method does work. However, by, notification: [message: "{{message|safe}}"] or using autoescape, both don't seem to store message safely.

Comment: Yes, The syntax error is in `waffle.flag('redirect_messages')`. Django template does not understand `()` parameter calls. You can write a template tag which does this logic for you..

Comment: But really, you'd be better off building up JSON in the view.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Actually, this is an open source project and it takes a little time till I understand these bits and pieces properly. Wasn't aware much about JSON in this code until I read this comment. Thank you! :) I've been reading about it. Any alternative to escape HTML in a JSON?